# Are conditionals" objects" in javascript? What "type" are they?

Tags: javascript

I've come across tutorials that say there are these "types" in javascript:

```
Number 
Boolean 
string 
null 
undefined 
object 
function 
array 
regex
```

But...what about conditionals?  Where do conditionals stand in relation to "types"?  Do conditionals even have types?

Comment: Are you talking about operators or statements, such as `if`?

Comment: Conditionals are operators. You can't assign a variable an operator value. You cannot use constructs either, like ```for``` or ```while```

Comment: What is meant by "conditionals" here? There are *conditional statements* (e.g. `if`).. or?

Comment: Typically, values or expressions can be said to "have types". Not everything in JavaScript is a value or an expression -- for example, `if` statements are not values or expressions.

Comment: What about providing some link to such "tutorials"? I feel you say "tutorials" but maybe those tutorials weren't telling you that, and it's just that you remember the meaning in the wrong way...!

Comment: It would be nice for them to be expressions though: `var sum = arr.reduce(+, 0);` :-)

Comment: @zerkms `arr.reduce(ops.plus, 0)` isn't too far fetched from that ;-)

Comment: @IsmailBadawi—only values have a type. Expressions may evaluate to some value and **that** may have a type, but the expression doesn't (it may evaluate to different values with different types).

Answer (score 2):

> Are conditionals“ objects” in javascript?

No. Only values have a [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8):

"An ECMAScript language type corresponds to values…"

> What “type” are they?

They don't have a type, they aren't values.

> Where do conditionals stand in relation to "types"?

They aren't values so they don't have a type.

> Do conditionals even have types?

No, they don't.

Answer (score 1):

A conditional expression is an evaluation or variable that affects the logic flow of a program. It is not a data type.

```
if(2 < 5){
  console.log("True!");
}else{
  console.log("I think something's broken...");
}
```

`2 < 5` is the conditional expression. Since it evaluates to `true`, the program proceeds to execute the code (conditional statement) under the `if` block. If for some reason it didn't, it would go to the `else`.

So, a conditional (expression) is not a data type at all: it's a piece of programming terminology.

By conditionals, you may be referring to `if` or `else`, which are also not data types.

Comment: "`2 < 5` is the conditional statement." --- it's a conditional *expression*. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5

Comment: "By conditionals, you may be referring to if, else if, or else" --- `else if` isn't a single unit. It's a compound one that contains of 2 separated `if` and `else` statements, so it must not be presented as a new type of language construct.

Comment: @zerkms Just because it's not its own language construct doesn't mean that the OP couldn't have been referring to it...

Comment: that's right. But the question is about terminology. There is nothing worse than providing something arbitrary in a precision subject. If a person mistakenly refers to something it makes sense to correct them, not confirm their misunderstanding

Comment: @zerkms: What about the `else for` and `else while` statements? ;-D Joking of course. You're right to make that distinction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but here you go:

**JavaScript Primary (Primitive) Data Types:**

- String
- Number
- Boolean

Unlike other languages, when specifying a variable in JavaScript, you don't specify the data type up front. Example

```
var myString = "Hello World"; //String
var myInteger = 1;            //Integer Variable
var myBool = true;              //Boolean Variable
```

Basically, JavaScript will take care of data types for you. It gets much deeper than this but this is a high level thread. For a deeper dive into what these data types do and how they're used, browse youtube for JavaScript Tutorials. Although, these videos are not to be used in a manner such as a bible or best practice but as a more visual source of information on how to do something. They are by no means considered the right way to do something but will definitely help guide you into a right direction.

**JavaScript Arithmetic Operators**

- `+` Addition (1 + 1)
- `-` Subtraction (1 - 1)
- `*` Multiplication (2 * 4)
- `/` Division (4 / 2)
- `%` Modulus (Remainder of 3 / 2)
- `++` Increment (i++)
- `--` Decrement (i--)

**JavaScript Comparison Operators**

- `==` Is Equal To ("Hello" == "Hello")
- `===` Is Exactly Equal To (true === true)
- `!=` Is Not Equal To ("true" != "false")
- `!==` Is Not Exactly Equal To ("true" !== true)
- `>` Greater Than (5 > 1)
- `<` Less Than (1 < 5)
- `>=` Greater Than or Equal To (4 >= 4)
- `<=` Less Than or Equal To (4 <= 4)

**JavaScript Logical Operators**

- `&&` And (2 > 1 && 1 > 0) `// Returns true`
- `||` Or (1 < 10 || 1 < -1) `// Returns true`
- `!` Not (!true)

Comment: "JavaScript Primary Data Types" --- who declared them so? What makes the other types non-primary?

Comment: "Primary Data Types"... did you mean "primitive"? If so, there are other primitives too.

Comment: "For a deep dive, browse youtube for JavaScript Tutorials" --- please **NO**. Please don't use any video tutorials for anything!

Comment: *"Unlike other languages..."* should be *"Unlike some other languages..."*

Comment: Microsoft refers to them as primary data types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8 - that's what you should rely on

Comment: Then that's their own categorization, but they do fit together into a category of primitives types that can represent more than a single value.

Comment: No argument in depending on that site over Microsoft.

Comment: There are **5** [primitive values](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2), the types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String.

Comment: How about `%` operator? Isn't it arithmetic?